# How can i get guild id in createguild event

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

how can i get guild id in this event `guildCreate.js` i tried `guild.id` gets `undefined` even `console.log(guild)` gets me blank space 
`client.guild.id` gives error `id`

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const config1 = require("../config.json");

module.exports = async (client, guild) => {

    // let msgs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./prefixsettings.json", "utf8"));
    console.log(guild)
    console.log(client.guild.id)    // this guild id is required below in place of client.guild.id
    // msgs[client.guild.id] = {
    //    prefixes: config1.prefix
    // };
    // await fs.writeFile("./prefixsettings.json", JSON.stringify(msgs), (err) => {
    //    if (err) throw err;
    //   console.log(`done`);

    // });
}
```

https://github.com/RootAndroid58/discordbotethyt/ 
my discord bots code

Comment: Can you give us a bit more context? Like, where is this module called from, how your bot is structured as a whole.

Comment: this module is in events named `guildCreate.js` every other event is working fine example `ready.js` and `guildMemberAdd` ,etc

Comment: consider the part console.log only in the above code ok let me edit the ablove code

Comment: The only difference I could find comparing this to a working bot of mine, that could cause it to be undefined is the "async" declaration before the function.
`module.exports = async (client, guild) => {`

Try removing it and see if it works, if It still is undefined, the problem is most likely not in this file.

Comment: i tried it not working my output is [https://pastebin.com/xYaNn57X](https://pastebin.com/xYaNn57X)

Comment: Then the issue is not in this file. It may be in another part of the bot logic.

Comment: ok then let me upload this bot on github

Comment: [https://github.com/RootAndroid58/discordbotethyt/](https://github.com/RootAndroid58/discordbotethyt/ ) my discordbot link

Comment: sir Thomas can u check my bot i have given the link

Comment: The code is in general very messy, especially with the indentation being all over the place, I'd recommend starting over if you feel like you have enough extra knowledge to make it better, re-writes can really make you learn a lot of good practices.
But, in your index.js, the main issue I found was in line 56, the declaration ```const [, matchedPrefix] = message.content.match(prefixRegex);``` has this weird [, matchedPrefix], I don't know how the bot even runs with that in there, change it for ```const matchedPrefix = message.content.match(prefixRegex);``` and maybe it wont break.

Comment: here is the client log i want to get id for this 637301291068030997 guild id I skipped other things https://pastebin.com/qGWscVbk can u check it out it gives me undefined on `console.log(client.guild.id)` where id is not defined `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`  `console.log(client.guild)` returns undefined where i am missing here is complete client log if cant understand that https://pastebin.com/P13gM4we

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

after line 1, then `client.guild.id` or `client.guilds.get('SERVER_ID')`should work.

You can get the server ID by rightclicking on the server name -> copy id